# How to watch Firebase Storage traffic requests from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I would like to watch network requests made from my app to Firebase servers (for debug purposes), especially Firebase Storage requests.

My app is written in Flutter, but Firebase traffic is not shown in the `Devtools` `Network` tab.

How can i watch this please either from the Devtools or any other tool ? (i am using MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing for the web too, you can use Chome DevTools.  I'm still developing my app using the Firebase emulators and the auth/firestore traffic is showing up in there.  I am not to the Storage part of my app yet, but likely it works if the other two do.

I don't get any network traffic in Flutter's own Devtools Network tab either.

Comment: Thanks but i am only developing for mobile, not sure i can use the Chrome devtools in this case as i don't run anything on web :/